# Changing CSS with JS Using variables

Tags: javascript, css, variables, border

I made a simple HTML file with a simple script.

I want to change the CSS border with values people fill in theirselves.
Its with thickness, style, color. Also I have 3 divs set up to test it on, it should only be assigned to 1 div.
When the user filled in the desired values, they should press GO and then the script is being executed.

This is my HTML

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>1</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
<table width="750" border="1" cellspacing="3" style="float:left;">
  <tr>
    <td width="318">Border thickness (thin, medium, thick)</td>
    <td width="419"><textarea id="BD">thin</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Border style (dashed, dotted, solid or double)</td>
    <td><textarea id="BS">dashed</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Border color (i.e. #000 or #FFF</td>
    <td><textarea id="BK">#0f0</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Which Div? ( one two or three?)</td>
    <td><textarea id="DN">two</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"></td>
    <td>&nbsp;<button>Go</button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

This is my Javascript

```
function border(){
    var thickness       = (document.getElementById("BD").value);
    var color               = (document.getElementById("BK").value);
    var style       = (document.getElementById("BD").value);
    var div         = (document.getElementById("DN").value);

    document.getElementById(div).style.border = "thickness, color, style";
}
```

and this is my CSS

```
#one{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    border:none;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
}
#two {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    border:none;
}
#three {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    border:none;
}
```

Quick recap.

If people fill in values for thickness(thick), color(#0f0) and style(dashed). The scripts turns them into variables, those variables should be set in the CSS AFTER the button(go) is clicked like so:

```
border: thick dashed #0F0;
```

(random order) and only for the DIV that was chosen by the user.

Edit: its usefull to add the question or problem.

The script im using does not do the trick. And i cannot find out why. I have been busy with it all day

Comment: ...and your question is....????

Comment: @Diodeus added my question... Wasnt to smart to miss out on that part

Comment: please add a js fiddle it will make it easier to debug

Comment: @JamesDaly Hi james, thanks for helping. At the JSFiddle it work but when I copy it into dreamweaver and test it (in chrome) it doesn't do a thing...

Comment: where are you putting the javascript?  put the javascript on the bottom of the page or in a window.onload = function () {

};

Comment: try not to put your javascript of the head of the document but right before the closing body tag

Comment: HI Chris, glad it worked - if you don't need anything else please choose my answer as the accepted answer by checking it so everyone knows the issue is closed - :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this
http://jsfiddle.net/gxTuG/

add an id to your button element then this is your javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var thickness = document.getElementById("BD").value
    var color = document.getElementById("BK").value
    var style = document.getElementById("BS").value
    var div = document.getElementById("DN").value
    var alltogether = thickness + ' ' + style + ' ' + color;
    //alert(alltogether);
    document.getElementById(div).style.border = alltogether;

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little something I've come up with after reading multiple other posts.

```
var getCssVar = function($var){
  return window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue(`${$var}`);
};

var setCssVar = function($var, $value) {
  return document.querySelector("html").style.setProperty($var, $value);
};
```